# How to trim values in custom format in excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, excel-2010

I have a column with values like 'ABCRSETCMS4008-M05'. Notice before the first '-' if there are more than 12 characters, I want to trim it to 12 characters. So my trimmed value should be 'ABCRSETCMS40-M05'. How can I do this in Excel? What should be my formula for this?

Also, there are values which have less than 12 characters. I don't want to affect those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Excel try-

```
=LEFT(TEXTBEFORE(A1,"-"),12)&"-"&TEXTAFTER(A1,"-")
```

For `google-sheet` try-

```
=LEFT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"-"),1,1),12)&"-"&INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"-"),1,2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try using `TEXTSPLIT()` in `MS365`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",,LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(A2,"-"),12))
```

---

In `Google Sheets`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=JOIN("-",INDEX(LEFT(SPLIT(A2,"-"),12)))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is a GS question. If so, try to use `REGEXREPLACE()`:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^([^-]{12})[^-]*","$1")
```

For a range of values:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="","",REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"^([^-]{12})[^-]*","$1")))
```